# Forward calls to messenger

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, calls, voip, telegram, ifttt

Is it possible to forward network calls on an Android mobile phone through a messenger, like Telegram or Whatsapp, to a set contact?

Could IFTTT be used for this?

Answer (score 1):

[Call forwarding](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_forwarding) is a telephony or carrier function. It works amongst voice networks or some VOIP sites. For it to work with messenger apps:

- They should mutually allow it, which is unlikely given the revenue models of voice calling (at times call forwarding is a paid service even for voice networks) .
- Security concerns - for example, if the calling number cannot be identified across messaging apps, it would not be permitted. There could be more such scenarios.
- Encryption. Voice calls of [WhatsApp are encrypted](https://www.whatsapp.com/security/). Same is the case with
  [Telegram](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telegram_(software)).
  They would not like to expose or let others use their proprietary encryption.

There may be more reasons too. Only after it is legally and financially viable a messaging app will expose an API that can be used for this. Till such time this is possible, automation is ruled out irrespective of the app